# Are there any Key listeners in python (v 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to do something like in bellow pseudo code. (key listener).

```
while (true)
{
    if('a' key pressed)
    {
        A(); // calling function A
    }
    else if('b' key pressed)
    {
        B();
    }
    else if('e' key pressed)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried this kind of program using 'win.getkey()', but is seems not working properly. how can i write a proper key listener in python ? (without 3rd party libraries)

Comment: What issue did you have with win.getkey()?

Comment: used { key = win.getkey()  ,  win.clear()  , win.addstr("Detected key:")  , win.addstr(str(key))  }  , 'Detected key:' is not displayed, and gets stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. It does not contain 3rd party module.

**Code:**

```
import sys, tty, os, termios


def getkey():
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
    try:
        while True:
            b = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 3).decode()
            if len(b) == 3:
                k = ord(b[2])
            else:
                k = ord(b)
            key_mapping = {
                127: 'backspace',
                10: 'return',
                32: 'space',
                9: 'tab',
                27: 'esc',
                65: 'up',
                66: 'down',
                67: 'right',
                68: 'left'
            }
            return key_mapping.get(k, chr(k))
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)


try:
    while True:
        k = getkey()
        print("Detected key: {}".format(k))
        if k == 'esc':
            quit()
        else:
            print(k)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    os.system('stty sane')
    print('stopping.')
```

**Test and output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Detected key: a
a
Detected key: s
s
Detected key: d
d
Detected key: f
f
Detected key: right
right
Detected key: left
left
Detected key: space
space
Detected key: tab
tab
stopping.
```

**Note:** If you are able to use an external Python module, I suggest a the `pynput` or `keyboard` Python module. Links: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard , https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput